# Running an In-Memory Sandboxed Neo4J Database for NodeJS Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, neo4j, jestjs

Is there a way to spin up small in-memory Neo4J database instances for use when unit testing NodeJS code? I am currently using Jest.

Answer (score 1):

[Testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-node) is a library for running databases in docker containers during integration, it works very well with the official [Neo4j docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j)